Texture on model is not the same color as sampeled color in texture paint mode
The texture on the model looks too bright. I sampeled the color from my refernce and it looks good on the texture itself. But on the model it looks wrong. I'm following this tutorial. Maybe it is because they use Blender 4.0 and I use 3.5 and emission works differently in the different versions? Here you can find my blender file.


Its the same color, just too bright, are you using base color or just the emission?

@Emir I'm new to texturepaint so, I not sure. But I use the emission shader (instead of principle BSDF) with the texture PNG as color. The the color on the png is the same as on the refernce. Just on the model it looks wrong.
